# How can I display query string after execution when parameters have been used in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm looking for a way how i can display query string after execution when parameters have been used in VB.net ..

for example :

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnect)
con.Open()
Using com As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO myTable (myColumn1, myColumn2) VALUES (@C1, @C2)", con)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C1", myValueForColumn1)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C2", myValueForColumn2)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

so I wish to display the query string with real values not with parameters

Comment: I think that your options are pretty limited. The simple 'one-off' approach would be to write a method after the query is executed  which takes the SQLCommand object and spins through the parameters collection replacing the parameter literals in the sql string variable with the actual values.  This obviously would be for display and/or logging.  You could get fancy and even use an aspect to do this on methods which do data access via Unity or PostSharp.

Answer (score 2):

The query string you're looking for doesn't exist. It is never created at any point. The whole purpose of parameterized queries is such that the data in the parameters is *never* subsituted into the command text, so that a data input like `';DROP TABLE myTable;--` *never* has a chance to be treated as code.

Remember: parameterized queries do not sanitize inputs: they quarantine them.

If you want to understand what's going on, think of it more as if you are running an sql procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @C1 nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @C2 nvarchar(50);

Set @C1 = imaginaryFunctionToGetValueFromDataSegmentOfConnection(1);
Set @C2 = imaginaryFunctionToGetValueFromDataSegmentOfConnection(2);

INSERT INTO myTable (myColumn1, myColumn2) VALUES (@C1, @C2);
```

The actual mechanism involved is [sp_executesql](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx&ei=I6trUJXmGYWWyAHJz4DACg&usg=AFQjCNGjQSFvBRhz0y_FraF8zYR3pvVbjQ&sig2=zv0ncG2kECpH3zMmV-LUJQ), if you want to know more information. If you want to get a real query for debugging, my advice is to write code to actually build something like the above snippet, with your values substituted in place of the function calls.

Comment: Thanks Joel Coehoorn ...  I think i must do it manually, coz i need to save query string in database for Audit trail purpose and also I insist to use parameter in the queries

Comment: @Sali Most database already have the option to save this kind of audit. Maybe you could look at a db solution and not a .net one.

Comment: @the_lotus : Tq ,You are right.  i'll try do this in database level